# Electric displacement - why are field lines continuous?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, vector-fields, dielectric

I recently attempted problem 4.17 in Griffiths's "Introduction to Electrodynamics" 3rd edition in which you are asked to make a sketch of the electric displacement vector **D** in and around a dielectric with no free charges. Griffiths states that the field lines are continous everywhere.

This confused me a lot. I assume we can say this because they are no free charges and hence the electric displacement vector is divergenceless (using Gauss's law inside a dielectric). Therefore the flux of the **D** through any closed surface is 0 (according to the divergence theorem). But why can we assume that the flux through a surface is proportional to the number of field lines that cross it? It's true in the case of the electric field **E**, as **E** satisfies an inverse square law (if it were an inverse cube law it wouldn't work, as then, for example, the flux through a sphere centered around a point charge would be proportional to the inverse of the distance from the point charge to the surface of the sphere, while the number of field lines would not depend on the radius of the sphere). So how can we claim the same holds for **D**, which in general does not satisfy an inverse square law (Griffiths emphasized that since **D** is not in general curless, we cannot write a law similar to Coulombs's law for **D**)?

In addition, how do we represent the strength of **D** on diagrams, when again we usually represent the strength of **E** as the density of field lines in a given point (number of field lines which intersect a small cross-sectional area), as this again depends on what kind of distance law **D** satisfies?

Comment: *But why can we assume that the flux through a surface is proportional to the number of field lines that cross it?* Isn't this how field lines are defined? The density of field lines you decide to draw should correspond to the strength of the field there, which directly relates to the flux. Maybe I'm missing something in what you are saying though.

Comment: @BioPhysicist If we define the density of field lines like that I agree. But I also thought of field lines as coming from free charges (as I have heard the expression that free charges are the source of **D**), so we can also draw them like the field lines of **E** - the number of field lines from a free charge source is proportional to the magnitude of the free charge. And far from the free charge, the field lines follow the direction of **D**. The second method I am describing doesn't appear to imply that the flux is the number of field lines.

Comment: @Peter - Field lines are an artificial tool we use to visualize fields, not a physical phenomena or quantity.  For that reason, you can define an arbitrary number of field lines passing through some surface.